# Disappearing reference to self in a block under ARC

Tags: objective-c-blocks, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having trouble figuring out why a __weak reference to self is disappearing in the following block. Following Jiva's advice found here 
http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=160 I make a __weak reference to self outside the completion block, then make a strong reference to that weak reference within the block to hold on to it for the duration of the block.

The problem I'm having is that the weak reference (weakSelf) comes up nil when the block executes, but if I just make the call to self directly in the block everything works.

```
- (void)fetchItemList:(NSArray *)itemList withHandler:(ItemFetchCompletion)completionHandler
{
    NSString *fetchString = [self fetchRequestUsingItemList:itemList];
    NSURL *fetchUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:fetchString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *itemListRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:fetchUrl];
    __weak FetchManager *weakSelf = self;   
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *itemListRequestWeakRef = itemListRequest;
    [itemListRequest setCompletionBlock:^{
        ASIHTTPRequest *itemListRequestStrongRef = itemListRequestWeakRef;
        ZAssert(weakSelf, @"weakSelf reference is nil.");
        FetchManager *strongSelf = weakSelf;        
        NSData *fetchedData = [itemListRequestStrongRef responseData];
        NSArray *fetchedItems = [strongSelf itemsFromFetchedData:fetchedData];
        completionHandler(fetchedItems);
    }];
    [itemListRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is essentially what your code is doing:

1. Making a weak variable, `weakSelf`.
2. Passing a block to a function that references that weak variable.

A this point, `self` is not retained by the block nor the `weakSelf` variable. Then, when the block runs, `weakSelf` is put into a `__strong` variable, thus retaining any value that was in `weakSelf`. Unfortunately, if the original value of `weakSelf`, namely `self` was already deallocated, `weakSelf` would be `nil` already.

The compiler can see what external variables your block accesses, and then adds any necessary retains if those variables are `__strong`. The compiler does not care that you assign a `__weak` variable to an internal variable that happens to be `__strong`. This retain will happen **when the block runs**, not when it is created.

By using `self` directly from the block, the compiler sees that you are referencing a variable that is not `__weak`, and therefore automatically retains that variable for the lifecycle of the block. In cases like this, I see no reason why you wouldn't directly reference self in the block, unless you are worried about a circular retain cycle.

Comment: Right, the weak/strong ref dance was to avoid a retain cycle. I don't know what was going on but there's nothing wrong with the code and, oddly enough, it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: Circular references shouldn't be a problem unless `self` keeps a strong reference to the block, which doesn't seem to be the case.